# Look up value in linked table beforeinserting corresponding value

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am over simplifying what can only really be called an annoyance, that I am wondering if there is an answer for.

*The following is just an example*

Say I have `tbl_user` with field `day` that is in a relationship with another table called `tbl_dayOfWeek`.

`tbl_user.day` takes a number that corresponds to the ID of `tbl_dayOfWeek`, where every `tbl_dayOfWeek.ID` is connected to a day of the week like `tbl_dayOfWeek.weekday`.

Now every time I want to insert a record into tbl_user, the data that I have is the day of the week as a String - for instance `"Monday"`. So before I can enter the record I must first make a select query every time to find the ID number that corresponds to the string day value that I have, in the tbl_dayOfWeek table.

My question is, is there a way to write the insert query where it looks up the corresponding day number when you give it the day string value, instead of me having to make two database calls to get the number of the string first, so that I can enter the number?

Something like: "INSERT INTO tbl_user (day) VALUES (tbl.dayOfWeek.ID) WHERE 'dayStringName' = tbl.dayOfWeek.weekday

Comment: Have a look at dLookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

`INSERT INTO tbl_user(day) VALUES((SELECT ID FROM tbl_dayOfWeek WHERE weekday = 'dayStringName'))`

Comment: Thank you, this was indeed what I was looking for and it worked after reading up more on "Select statements inside Insert statements"